# Increment int value in ObjC setter/getter

Tags: objective-c

I cannot figure this out. I need some help please.

This is in my viewController.h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int count;
```

It holds the amount of times a user shows a specific screen. (the viewDidLoad method is called).

Every time the viewDidLoad method runs, I call this method to increment the count:

```
- (void)returnCount{
    NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.count];
    NSLog(@"%@",num);
    if ([num intValue] == 0) {
        self.count = 0;
        NSLog(@"This worked and now the nil number is :%i",self.count);
    }else{
        self.count = self.count + 1;
        NSLog(@"This worked and now the 0 number is :%i",self.count);
    }
```

self.count is used in my code in conditional statements (if self.count == 0) then do something, if (self.count > 1) then do something else.

Each time it is called, self.count remains 0. How can I correctly increment this by one?

Thank you

Comment: What's the point of the `if` statement in your `returnCount` method? It will never be true and even if it could be, you return the same thing regardless of whether it is true or not.

Comment: `num` is an `NSNumber` object, so `(num == 0)` is equivalent to `(num == nil)`. If you want the int value, you should use `([num intValue] == 0)`.

Comment: Your question is confusing, is this really the code you are using?

Comment: Yeah, your question makes no sense (nor does the code you supply).

Comment: Sorry, let me edit it

Comment: Why on earth to you stash an int into an NSNumber and then check the intValue? Can you explain that to us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the count will be reset to 0 every time the view controller is recreated (and viewDidLoad runs). You should create a static int which can be done like this,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    static int count = 0;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    count +=1;
    NSLog(@"%d",count);
}
```

The static int is initialized only once in the lifetime of a run, and retains its value even though the controller gets deallocated when you go away from it. It will retain this value even if the app goes into the background. It only gets reset if the app is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes no sense to me...

Simplified version of your code is

```
if (self.count == 0) {

}else{
    self.count += 1;
}
```

which does nothing if `self.count` is 0 and unless you set it to non-zero value somewhere else, it will stay at 0.

remove the `if` check, only keep `self.count += 1;` or do `self.count = 1` in your `init` method

Comment: i just did the self.count +=1 and it only increments once. it is always 1

Answer (score 0):

When exactly are you expecting an increment to occur? Your code:

```
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.count];
NSLog(@"%@",num);
if ([num intValue] == 0) {
    self.count = 0;
    NSLog(@"This worked and now the nil number is :%i",self.count);
}else{
    self.count = self.count + 1;
    NSLog(@"This worked and now the 0 number is :%i",self.count);
}
```

The relevant part of which can be written more simply as:

```
if (self.count == 0) {
    self.count = 0;
}else{
    self.count = self.count + 1;
}
```

On what occasion do you think `self.count = self.count + 1` will be performed? If `count` is zero it will remain zero. It will be zero initially per the rules pertaining to object allocation. So based on the code you've posted it will always be zero.